# Error when deploying using Team Project CI/CD

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to build a very simple CI/CD to deploy Website from Team Project Git to Azure Web App. The builds that I'm using was from Azure Web App builds definition template. The only things I modified was the Azure Subscription and App Service.
When the builds completed, I got the following error .

[image]

I tried to google, but to no avail. I have cross checked all the suggestions from Google, and found that those configurations are already defined in my builds definition.

I was wondering, is the zip file will be automatically created after "Build solution" step success?

====== EDIT 1 ======== .
Previously, the solution I used was generated from Mac Visual Studio Community.

So, I create an entirely new team project and imported the Sample Application from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-4?tabs=vsts). Guess what, it is working.
Now I'm suspecting the VSTS CI/CD does not support file generated by Mac Visual Studio Community.

Comment: Did you add additional msbuild arguments to specify where the package located in VS Build task? And can you show the detail build logs by setting variable system.debug as true?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error you posted the build system has not found the artifact so far when you are running the azure task.

The artifacts exist after the 'publish artifact drop' task has finished.
You have to put your azure publishing task after the build finished pushing your artifacts. In your case it should be your last task in the sequence.